# How to do a custom redirect to a new url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I have generated an rss feed in my custom component in my joomla site.

I am using ARTIO SEF in my joomla site for configuring SEF urls, and i changed the SEF url for the rss feed to something like this: `http://www.mysite.com/rss.xml`

But i am getting a 404 page when i visit that url.

However this url is working: `http://www.mysite.com/rss-xml`

I am confused at what changes i need to make to my site (or .htaccess file) to make a custom redirect to the `rss-xml` page when a user visits `rss.xml` page.

(Note: I am using localhost initially for development.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 303 /rss.xml /rss-xml
```

Comment: This logic is working in my localhost root folder (htdocs), but when i add this line in the .htaccess file of my joomla folder, it is not working.

Comment: Then try and update the relative path. Instead of /rss.xml and /rss-xml type in joomla/rss.xml joomla/rss-xml.

Comment: Thanks... finally got it working in my localhost joomla folder, using this line in its .htaccess file: Redirect 303 /joomla/rss.xml /joomla/rss-xml

Comment: And I hope that in order to make it work in the real site, i have to use: Redirect 303 /rss.xml /rss-xml

Comment: Surely this should be a 301 redirect. I assume that it is your intention that any user-agent (read crawler) that has visited the old link should no longer attempt to access the 'old' link, and should remember the new address. That's pretty much the definition of a 301 redirect.